# Which object detection pre-trained models are available and convertible with TensorRT?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, pre-trained-model, tensorrt, nvidia-jetson

I'm looking into converting a pre-trained object detection model with TensorRT to try it out on my NVIDIA Jetson TX2 but every model I find has layers that are not yet supported by TensorRT. So far I tried SSD with MobileNet and Faster R-CNN but they both have operations such as Identity that are not supported by TensorRT and I can't find many other TensorFlow models out there.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This repo has the pre-trained models you are looking for, along with instructions on how to take a model and build a TensorRT engine: https://github.com/NVIDIA-Jetson/tf_to_trt_image_classification#download